# Grunt : watch multiple files (js,css and gsp) within different sub folders

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I am using grunt/watch for the first time:

My Gruntfile.js is configured as follows:

module.exports = function(grunt) {

```
  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
      watch: {
        all: {
          options: { 
            livereload: true 
          },
          files: ['**/*.gsp,**/.css']
        }
      }
  });

  // Load the plugin that provides the "uglify" task.
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

};
```

The problem i am facing is when i run the watch task to check only css or gsp file type like `files: ['**/.css']` or  `files: ['**/.gsp']`  it works fine and detects changes in the files but when i try to watch them both  `files: ['**/*.gsp,**/.css']`, it doesn't detect any changes *(keeps showing waiting on the command line)*. **How to make it work so that it detects the changes in both the file types .?**

**At the end of the day i want to do this ( image) :**

[image]

Any insight will be helpful..Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best syntax will be:
`files: ['./{,*/}*.{gsp,css}']`
As you can see grunt accepts arrays of extensions

Ok, bassed in your edit, this should be the best solution

```
files: ['./grails-app/{,*/}*.gsp',
        './web-app/{,*/}*.{css,gsp}']
```

Comment: yep, sorry forgot to add path ./ should be fine now

Comment: Can you post your file tree?, i'm guessing you want recoursive search

Comment: I have editted my answer, hope everything work as you expected.

Comment: Thanks for your time...it worked...and also i found that if we have subfolders within web-app and grails-app folder we need to add ** (double star) before mentioning file type ( as anton below answered )...like this -
 files: ['./grails-app/{,**/}*.gsp','./web-app/{,**/}*.{css,js}']}

Answer (score 1):

It is probably easier and more readable to express the functionality you want in the following way:

```
files: ['**/*.gsp', '**/*.css']
```

And for the file hierarchy you just posted:

```
files: [ 'grails-app/**/*.gsp', 'web-app/**/*.css', 'web-app/**/*.js' ]
```